# Creating snippet for shared model

Tags: spring-restdocs

Is it possible to generate snippet for a nested bean shared between different response structures ?

Address model

```
class Address {
 String state;
 Integer postcode;
}
```

Response from endpoint 1 (R1)

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "address": {
    "state": "abc",
    "postcode": 3
  }
}
```

Response from endpoint 2 (R2)

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "currentAddress": {
    "state": "abc",
    "postcode": 2
  }
}
```

I would like to generate the snippet for `Address` model once and reuse it in generated snippets for R1 and R2.

Answer (score 1):

As [described in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads-fields), you can use `subsectionWithPath("address")` and `subsectionWithPath("currentAddress")` to document the address subsection in R1 and R2 and then cross-link to a separate section in your documentation that describes the address structure in detail. The REST Docs samples show [an example of this cross-linking](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/429d6da222fdb8cb81ca271373cf9563bbe47aa5/samples/rest-notes-spring-hateoas/src/test/java/com/example/notes/ApiDocumentation.java#L145-L146).

To describe the address structure in detail, you can use [a combination of `responseFields` and `beneathPath`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads-subsections-fields) to generate a snippet for a specific part of a response.